# hadoop creates dir that cannot be found

Tags: hadoop, mkdir

I use the following hadoop command to create a directory

```
 hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/testing/morehere1
```

I get the following message:

```
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
```

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Not understanding the error, I run the command again, which returns this message:

```
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
 mkdir: `/tmp/testing/morehere2': File exists
```

then when I try to go to the directory just created, it's not there.

```
cd /tmp/testing/morehere2
 -bash: cd: /tmp/testing/morehere2: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It says `File exists` but not directory. Can you recheck for file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/testing/morehere1
```

This command created a directory in the hdfs . Dont worry about the log4j warning . The command created the directory successfully . That is why you got the error  mkdir: `/tmp/testing/morehere2': File exists` the second time you tried the command .

The following command will not work , since the directory is not created in your local filesystem , but in hdfs .

```
cd /tmp/testing/morehere2
```

Use the command below to check the created directory in hdfs :

```
hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/testing
```

You should be able to see the new directory there .

About the log4j warning : You can ignore that as it will not cause your hadoop commands to fail . But if you want to correct it , you can add a File appender to log4j.properties .

Answer (score 1):

Remember that there's a difference between HDFS and your local file system. That first line that you posted creates a directory in HDFS, not on your local system. So you can't cd to it or ls it or anything directly; if you want to access it, you have to through hadoop. It's also very rare to be logging to HDFS as file appends have never been well-supported. I suspect that you actually want to be creating that directory locally, and that might be part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your MR code were running fine previously and Now its showing this log4j error then restart all the hadoop daemons. It may solve your problem as it solves mine :)